# Searching for a binary tree for a vehicle with a given name

Tags: java, tree

I'm searching my binary search tree of `Vehicle` objects and I'm just wondering whether there would be much point, if it's best practice to search to see if a node has a left/right child first like so:

```
return n.hasLeft() ? find(name, n.left()) : null;
```

Or just go with the following, since it will return `null` if it doesn't exist anyway:

```
return find(name, n.left());
```

Here's the code for the whole method:

```
protected Vehicle find(String name, Node n)
{
    if (n == null) return null;

    int order = name.compareTo(n.getVehicleName());

    if (order == 0)
        return n.getVehicle();  
    else if (order < 0)
        return n.hasLeft() ? find(name, n.left()) : null;       
    else 
        return n.hasRight() ? find(name, n.right()) : null;
}
```

Would checking first be more efficient since it saves an extra recursive call being made?

Comment: If you want to know if there is a performance difference is this detail, I'd recommend finding a benchmarking tool and benchmark it. However, you might want to consider other aspects of it too. Either way, I would recommend to choose one way and be happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if (n == null) return null;`statement in `find()` is the only base case that you need. Checking for `n.hasLeft()` is redundant, and it doesn't even reduce the total number of function calls, since `n.hasLeft()` is itself a function call.